# Maximum throughput for Batch Apex?

Tags: apex, batch

I am working on a system that currently relies on **batch apex** to process ten of thousands of records by hitting an **external API** to pass data to another system for processing.

We get a "success" or "error" response from the HTTP request, and then later, we receive a post back to see the true processing state of the API call.

If each of these API calls takes **1 sec to process**, and I am running 50k of these, then what would be my maximum throughput in external API calls/second?

Right now, it appears that since I am using a call to `Database.executeBatch(batchToStart, TOTAL_BATCH_SIZE);`, then everything is running sequentially, and I am getting **1 call API / per second**.

I believe I could split the job up manually into batches and get a **maximum of 5** calls / per second ( if no other jobs are running). Is this correct?

I can only have 5 jobs running in parallel, and there is no way to run the API calls in parallel within the job.

> Additionally ( thanks to @identigral )

This post : [Throttling http callouts across queueables executed in parallel](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190010/throttling-http-callouts-across-queueables-executed-in-parallel)

Indicates that if we move to Queuable, then we could get a max of  **50 calls per second**. Is this the correct conclusion?

I would like 1000 calls / second , do I need to move off of platform?

Comment: Consider that there are limits on the number of async executions per day (250000 or 200 * platform user licenses, whichever is larger) and that each call to a batch start/execute/finish is an async call. Also consider that you can start up to 50 queueables from a given synchronous transaction and these are not limited for concurrent processing in the same way as batches.

Comment: Obviously queueable executions also consume an async process per execute method call.

Comment: Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190010/throttling-http-callouts-across-queueables-executed-in-parallel. There's other similar Q&As that rehash this subject, do a search.

Comment: I would suggest you look to see if your external system API be updated to receive composite sets of data... or consider some middleware.

Comment: @PhilW - I am going to explore Queuable, and update my question.  Do you know the parallelism allowed on queueable?  If each API call was a Queable, what throughput could I get.

Comment: @identigral thanks for that link, I read it and it indicates the opposite problem. That OP is able to push salesforce to the limit of the external system.  I am unable to do that because I am unable to achieve the parallelism I am looking for.  Even at 50 in parallel, I would only get 50 calls / second. But it would help.

Comment: Saw your edit... As an aside, if each call takes 1 full second, spawning 1000 concurrent calls per second would probably crash the far side (I've seen this happen). But, let's say you really wanted to do this... Use Apex to call a Heroku or AWS EB app, and have it spawn a thousand calls at once. I'm not sure how much this would cost in dynos, but it might be worth it.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox -- I am fairly confident that this is where we will land. I just want to confirm that the general understanding is correct before making the recommendation. I am a little surprised that the platform does not support greater async scale, but then I guess they did buy mulesoft.

Answer (score 3):

There's a variety of factors at play, but we can go through them. First, there's the start method itself. Only one start method can be running at once, so we would want optimally fast start methods to get up to speed as fast as possible. Second, there is typically a small delay between execute calls (I've seen it be as bad as about four seconds), so we want to minimize the number of execute methods, which means maximizing the number of callouts per transaction, ideally 100.

Assuming you can get that kind of situation, you could reach an average of 288 callouts per minute, assuming each callout lasts 1 second and a there is a 4 second delay between execute methods. 50k records at this speed takes about 2 hours, 53 minutes, and 36 seconds. This time would be significantly reduced during evening and night hours when the systems are less active; if we assume a 1/2 second delay instead, we get very close to 300 callouts per minute, or about 2 hours, 47 minutes, and 24 seconds. Not very much difference, since the callout times dominate the transaction speed.

On the other hand, if you use only one callout per execute, you're looking at 1 callout per second on average (across 5 batches), it would take close to 2 days, 21 hours, 26 minutes, and 40 seconds for 50,000 records given a 4 second delay between execute calls, or 13 hours, 53 minutes, and 20 seconds with a 0.5 second delay between each call. The actual value is going to be somewhere between those two extremes, perhaps around 26-28 hours.

Overall, the more you can do per transaction, the faster you'll get done. Keep in mind that execution units also have to deal with other transactions like Queueable, future, and scheduled methods, so keep those elements in mind when you design your Batchable process. Even a single Batchable that runs expediently should be sufficient to handle the volume you're talking about.

Comment: Appreciate this response. From your math, it looks like no matter what I do; these API calls will take hours to process.  I don't think there is a way to get the parallelism since each batch process is single-threaded.  Right?

Comment: @digidigo Correct, but I also suspect your third-party can't handle 1000 calls/sec. That's not necessarily a realistic goal. I am curious about why this requirement, what kind of hardware or service is involved, and perhaps if there might be another way. If you want to contact me, you can reach me with the info on my profile, or set up a chat room here, whatever you feel most comfortable with.